# Emailing Script after Sort Broke

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have posted about this on here so I hope it's ok to ask in regards to a separate issue with this code.

I have the script email when new submissions are sent in using a form.  It was working great but then I wanted to sort newest on top and now I get no emails.  What did I miss in this script?

Sort Script

```
// Dirty but works
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
var ASCENDING = false;

var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;


var activeSheet;

function autoSort(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {

    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}


function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;

  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
    autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
}


function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}

function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}
```

### Email Script

```
function SendEmail() {
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,19);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 for (i in AllValues) {
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[19];

 if (EmailSent == "Sent") 
     continue;

  message =
      "<p><b>Email?: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>District: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor Cost: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor Cost: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Default Price: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor SKU: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Manufacturer: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Manufacturer SKU: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Barcode: </b>" + CurrentRow[10] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>Category: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Device: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Model: </b>" + CurrentRow[13] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>Color: </b>" + CurrentRow[14] + "</p>";


  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;


  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 19).setValue("Sent");
}


 var SendTo = "@vzwpix.com";
 var SendToEmail = "davidm";
 

  var Subject = "New Sku:" +" "+ CurrentRow[13] +" " +"From:"+" "+CurrentRow[1];

  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
  
   MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendToEmail,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
  

}
```

### Alternate Working Script

I adjusted my script to search for empty column and send mail
Here is the Script:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3; // Start at second row because the first row contains the data labels
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()

  // Fetch the range of cells, in this case A2:T
  // Column B, row[2] = Email Address, Column C, row[1] = Name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, lastCol)
  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[1]; // 
    var message = 
      "<p><b>Email?: </b>" + row[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>District: </b>" + row[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor Cost: </b>" + row[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor Cost: </b>" + row[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Default Price: </b>" + row[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor: </b>" + row[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Vendor SKU: </b>" + row[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Manufacturer: </b>" + row[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Manufacturer SKU: </b>" + row[9] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Barcode: </b>" + row[10] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>Category: </b>" + row[11] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Device: </b>" + row[12] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Model: </b>" + row[13] + "</p>"+
      "<p><b>Color: </b>" + row[14] + "</p>"
    
    
    
    ; // Assemble the body text
        var cell = row[19]; // Last column
    if (cell == "") { 
   var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "PHONE@vzwpix.com",
      cc: "",
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see how can we know what you've missed. Do you get any errors when you run the code? Can you test each part of the code to make sure it works as expected?

Comment: I get no error codes at all.  It basically just does not send email.. my guess is its looking at END instead of at the top of sheet.

Comment: Can you try testing different parts in isolation? Does `MailApp.sendEmail` actually work? Is the message formatted correctly? etc

Comment: I have done what you mentioned.  SendEmail works perfect as long as i disable the sort.  The script works as expected. It seems to be the sorting to the top that breaks it